# Switch case in closure form not matching properly

Tags: regex, string, groovy, switch-statement, closures

I'm trying to make a switch case based on partial strings using Groovy's pattern matching. I've already got this working -

```
String s = "abc";

switch(s){
  case { it =~ /b/ } :
    //this works
    break;
 .....
}
```

But when I try to abstract out the closure I run into issues -

```
String s = "abc";
def partialMatch = {string, pattern -> string =~ /$pattern/}

switch(s){
  case partialMatch(s, "b"):
    //this doesn't work
    break;
 .....
}
```

It seems like the match is working, but the case still doesn't trigger for some reason. Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd need to put `partialMatch` in a Closure for it to be executed by the `switch`:

```
case {partialMatch(s, "b")}:
```